# Yesod Sessionless Authentication

Tags: authentication, haskell, basic-authentication, yesod, bearer-token

I am using Yesod to build a purely REST backend for an Angular based application.  This application will be hosted separately with a CDN and will need to connect to the Yesod api as well as a few others.  Is there a way to have Yesod accept a Bearer token instead of using a cookie session for authentication?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We do something similar in www.fpcomplete.com. You can do this by overriding the `maybeAuthId` method in the `YesodAuth` typeclass to check for the Bearer token. For fpcomplete.com, we check for an authorization request header, which looks something like:

```
req <- waiRequest
mUserId <-
    case lookup "authorization" (requestHeaders req) of
        Nothing -> doNormalAuthentication
        Just authHeader -> checkAuthHeader
```